# Matplot lib Error " AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get' "

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I don't know how to solve this Erorr?
Can somebody help me with this?

I first separate Date time in some attribute so i can make
some different graphs.

```
uber2015 ['Pickup_date'] = pd.to_datetime(uber2015['Pickup_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
uber2015 ['DayofWeekNum'] = uber2015['Pickup_date'].dt.dayofweek
uber2015['Month'] = uber2015['Pickup_date'].dt.month
uber2015['Hour'] = uber2015['Pickup_date'].dt.hour
uber2015['Day'] = uber2015 ['Pickup_date'].dt.day
print(uber2015.head(5))
```

```
# Uber pickups by Hour in NYC
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
ax = uber2015 = sns.countplot(x= "Hour", data=uber2015, color="lightsteelblue")
ax.set_xlabel('Hour of the Day', fontsize = 12)
ax.set_ylabel('Count of Uber Pickups', fontsize = 12)
ax.set_title('Uber Pickups by HOur in NYC (Jan-Jun 2015)', fontsize = 16)
ax.tick_params(labelsize = 8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this a typo `ax = uber2015 = sns.countplot`? Did you mean `ax = sns.countplot`?

Comment: I suppose you have run this code more than once within the same kernel. The second time you run it, your data is overwritten by `ax = uber2015 = sns.countplot(...)`. Replace that by `ax = sns.countplot(...)` to not throw away your data.